# What is the difference between "because of" and "by reason of"?

Tags: meaning

Do you know what the differences are between *because of* and *by reason of*? According to collinsdictionary.com they mean the same thing, supposing they were correct, how can I use them?

[collisndictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/ingles/by-reason-of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between *because of* and *by reason of*. One of Merriam Webster's definitions of *because of* is literally *by reason of*.

The real difference between the two phrases is their levels of formality: *Because of* is less formal than *by reason of*.

As a native English speaker, I can't think of an instance when I'd use *by reason of* in anything other than a legal context. I.e. "He was found not-guilty by reason of insanity."

Even in a formal setting, you'd sound pretentious if you said *by reason of* unless you were using it in the legal context.

Answer (score 0):

The practical difference is that *by reason of* sounds formal, awkward and stiff.  Because of this, *because of* is far more common, about 100 times more common according to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=because%20of%2C%20by%20reason%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbecause%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbecause%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBecause%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cby%20reason%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bby%20reason%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBy%20reason%20of%3B%2Cc0).  Personally, I have never said *by reason of*.